# merging two dataframes based on two columns of values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I am doing a machine learning project, and I am now on the data processing part. Anyway, I have two dataframes as shown -

```
   Final_Lat   Final_Lot  Label
0   37.23140    -121.75853  1.0
1   37.34883    -121.88834  1.0
2   37.31835    -121.85878  1.0
3   37.26027    -121.87655  1.0
4   37.30793    -121.79955  1.0
5   37.24895    -121.87519  1.0


   TestLat      TestLot
0   37.20000    -122.00000
1   37.20000    -121.99999
2   37.20000    -121.99998
3   37.20000    -121.99997
4   37.20000    -121.99996
5   37.20000    -121.99995
6   37.20000    -121.99994
7   37.20000    -121.99993
```

What I want is to move labels of 1 to the coordinate that has appeared in the same list which will look something like this. and It should also contains the information from the second data frame.

```
Final_Lat   Final_Lot  Label
0   37.23140    -121.75853  1.0
1   37.34883    -121.88834  1.0
2   37.31835    -121.85878  1.0
3   37.20000    -122.00000  nan
4   37.20000    -121.99999  nan
2   37.20000    -121.99998  nan
```

I have tired

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'Final_Lat': Trian['Lat'].apply(float), 
                     'Final_Lot': Trian['Lot'].apply(float),
                     'Label': Trian['L'].apply(float),})

right = pd.DataFrame({'Final_Lat': Fullcoordinate['TestLat'].apply(float), 
                      'Final_Lot': Fullcoordinate['TestLot'].apply(float)})

Final_result = pd.merge(left, right, how='right',on=['Final_Lot','Final_Lat'])
```

And it didn't work. I would appreciate any help!

```
right = pd.DataFrame({'Final_Lat': Fullcoordinate['TestLat'](lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).mul(1000).fillna(0).astype(int) , 
                      'Final_Lot': Fullcoordinate['TestLot'](lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).mul(1000).fillna(0).astype(int) })
```

Comment: Can you please explain your output?

Comment: Yea! Basically I am doing a crime prediction project, and Test Lat and Lot are the all the possible combinations of coordinates in an area and Final Lat and Lot are the coordinates where crimes has happened before. I am trying to merge this two list together, so that coordinates that has crime happened will be tabled as 1. I hope that's clear...

Answer (score 0):

So problem here is merge with `float` values because precision, I suggest convert columns multiple by `1000` and convert to integers and `merge` by this new columns:

```
old_cols = ['Final_Lat','Final_Lot']
new_cols = ['Final_Lat_int','Final_Lot_int']

Trian[new_cols] = Trian[old_cols].mul(1000).astype(int)
Final_Lat[new_cols] = Final_Lat[old_cols].mul(1000).astype(int)
```

If possible problem with `invalid literal for int` there is possible some non numeric values, one possible solution is convert them to `NaN` and then to `0`:

```
Trian[new_cols] = Trian[old_cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).mul(1000).astype(int)
Final_Lat[new_cols] = Final_Lat[old_cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).mul(1000).astype(int)
```

---

```
Final_result = pd.merge(Trian.drop(old_cols, axis=1),  
                        Final_Lat,
                        how='right',
                        on=new_cols)
print (Final_result)
   Label  Final_Lat_int  Final_Lot_int  Final_Lat  Final_Lot
0    NaN          37200        -122000       37.2 -122.00000
1    NaN          37200        -121999       37.2 -121.99999
2    NaN          37200        -121999       37.2 -121.99998
3    NaN          37200        -121999       37.2 -121.99997
4    NaN          37200        -121999       37.2 -121.99996
5    NaN          37200        -121999       37.2 -121.99995
6    NaN          37200        -121999       37.2 -121.99994
7    NaN          37200        -121999       37.2 -121.99993
```

Comment: wouldn't that lose some information when it compares the Test Lot and Lat to Final Lot and Lat?

Comment: nvm, I see the multiple part. Let me give it try rn

Comment: it gives me this error...ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: @YunxiaoJia - Mybe some missing values, how working `.mul(1000).fillna(0).astype(int)` ?

Comment: @YunxiaoJia - So problem is some non numeric values, need .apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).mul(1000).fillna(0).astype(int)

Comment: now it says TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable...let me edit my question, so you can see what i changed

Comment: @YunxiaoJia - Problem is if use your solution, then lost your original column. So need create another one new columns filled by integers - check my edited answer.

Comment: kernel just crashed...the file is too big

Comment: Anyway, I appreciate the help!  gonna try it again tomorrow.

Comment: @YunxiaoJia - I really big files pandas need a lot of RAM. Maybe dask should be better.